# GRU implementation in Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning, gated-recurrent-unit

Based on the LSTM code provided in the official Theano tutorial (http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/lstm.py), I changed the LSTM layer code (i.e. the functions `lstm_layer()` and `param_init_lstm()`) to perform a GRU instead.

The provided LSTM code trains well, but not the GRU I coded: the accuracy on the training set with the LSTM goes up to 1 (train cost = 0), while with the GRU it stagnates at 0.7 (train cost = 0.3).

Below is the code I use for the GRU. I kept the same function names as in tutorial, so that one can copy paste the code directly in it. What could explain the poor performance of the GRU?

```
import numpy as np
def param_init_lstm(options, params, prefix='lstm'):
    """
    GRU
    """
    W = np.concatenate([ortho_weight(options['dim_proj']),  # Weight matrix for the input in the reset gate
                        ortho_weight(options['dim_proj']),
                        ortho_weight(options['dim_proj'])], # Weight matrix for the input in the update gate  
                        axis=1)         
    params[_p(prefix, 'W')] = W

    U = np.concatenate([ortho_weight(options['dim_proj']),  # Weight matrix for the previous hidden state in the reset gate
                        ortho_weight(options['dim_proj']),
                        ortho_weight(options['dim_proj'])], # Weight matrix for the previous hidden state in the update gate
                        axis=1)         
    params[_p(prefix, 'U')] = U

    b = np.zeros((3 * options['dim_proj'],)) # Biases for the reset gate and the update gate        
    params[_p(prefix, 'b')] = b.astype(config.floatX)    
    return params


def lstm_layer(tparams, state_below, options, prefix='lstm', mask=None):
    nsteps = state_below.shape[0]
    if state_below.ndim == 3:
        n_samples = state_below.shape[1]
    else:
        n_samples = 1

    def _slice(_x, n, dim):
        if _x.ndim == 3:
            return _x[:, :, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]
        return _x[:, n * dim:(n + 1) * dim]

    def _step(m_, x_, h_):
        preact = tensor.dot(h_, tparams[_p(prefix, 'U')])
        preact += x_

        r = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 0, options['dim_proj'])) # reset gate
        u = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 1, options['dim_proj'])) # update gate

        U_h_t = _slice( tparams[_p(prefix, 'U')], 2, options['dim_proj'])
        x_h_t = _slice( x_, 2, options['dim_proj'])

        h_t_temp = tensor.tanh(tensor.dot(r*h_, U_h_t) + x_h_t)
        h = (1. - u) * h_ + u * h_t_temp        
        h = m_[:,None] * h + (1. - m_)[:,None] * h_

        return h

    state_below = (tensor.dot(state_below, tparams[_p(prefix, 'W')]) +
                   tparams[_p(prefix, 'b')])

    dim_proj = options['dim_proj'] 
    rval, updates = theano.scan(_step,
                                sequences=[mask, state_below],
                                outputs_info=[tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                           n_samples,
                                                           dim_proj)],
                                name=_p(prefix, '_layers'),
                                n_steps=nsteps)

    return rval[0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue comes from the last line, `return rval[0]`: it should instead be `return rval`.

The LSTM code provided in the official Theano tutorial (http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/lstm.py) uses `return rval[0]` because `outputs_info` contains 2 elements:

```
rval, updates = theano.scan(_step,
                            sequences=[mask, state_below],
                            outputs_info=[tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                       n_samples,
                                                       dim_proj),
                                          tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                                                       n_samples,
                                                       dim_proj)],
                            name=_p(prefix, '_layers'),
                            n_steps=nsteps)
return rval[0]
```

In the GRU, `outputs_info` contains just one element:

```
outputs_info=[tensor.alloc(numpy_floatX(0.),
                           n_samples,
                           dim_proj)],
```

and despite the brackets, it won't return a list of a list of Theano variables representing the outputs of scan, but directly a Theano variable.

The `rval` is then fed to a pooling layer (in this case, a mean pooling layer):

[image]

By taking only `rval[0]` in the GRU, since in the GRU code `rval` is a Theano variable and not a list of a Theano variables, you removed the part in the red rectangle:

[image]

which means you tried to perform the sentence classification just using the first word.

---

Another GRU implementation that can be plugged in the LSTM tutorial:

```
# weight initializer, normal by default
def norm_weight(nin, nout=None, scale=0.01, ortho=True):
    if nout is None:
        nout = nin
    if nout == nin and ortho:
        W = ortho_weight(nin)
    else:
        W = scale * numpy.random.randn(nin, nout)
    return W.astype('float32')

def param_init_lstm(options, params, prefix='lstm'):
    """
    GRU. Source: https://github.com/kyunghyuncho/dl4mt-material/blob/master/session0/lm.py
    """
    nin = options['dim_proj']
    dim = options['dim_proj']
    # embedding to gates transformation weights, biases
    W = numpy.concatenate([norm_weight(nin, dim),
                           norm_weight(nin, dim)], axis=1)
    params[_p(prefix, 'W')] = W
    params[_p(prefix, 'b')] = numpy.zeros((2 * dim,)).astype('float32')

    # recurrent transformation weights for gates
    U = numpy.concatenate([ortho_weight(dim),
                           ortho_weight(dim)], axis=1)
    params[_p(prefix, 'U')] = U

    # embedding to hidden state proposal weights, biases
    Wx = norm_weight(nin, dim)
    params[_p(prefix, 'Wx')] = Wx
    params[_p(prefix, 'bx')] = numpy.zeros((dim,)).astype('float32')

    # recurrent transformation weights for hidden state proposal
    Ux = ortho_weight(dim)
    params[_p(prefix, 'Ux')] = Ux
    return params


def lstm_layer(tparams, state_below, options, prefix='lstm', mask=None):

    nsteps = state_below.shape[0]

    if state_below.ndim == 3:
        n_samples = state_below.shape[1]
    else:
        n_samples = state_below.shape[0]

    dim = tparams[_p(prefix, 'Ux')].shape[1]

    if mask is None:
        mask = tensor.alloc(1., state_below.shape[0], 1)

    # utility function to slice a tensor
    def _slice(_x, n, dim):
        if _x.ndim == 3:
            return _x[:, :, n*dim:(n+1)*dim]
        return _x[:, n*dim:(n+1)*dim]

    # state_below is the input word embeddings
    # input to the gates, concatenated
    state_below_ = tensor.dot(state_below, tparams[_p(prefix, 'W')]) + \
        tparams[_p(prefix, 'b')]
    # input to compute the hidden state proposal
    state_belowx = tensor.dot(state_below, tparams[_p(prefix, 'Wx')]) + \
        tparams[_p(prefix, 'bx')]

    # step function to be used by scan
    # arguments    | sequences |outputs-info| non-seqs
    def _step_slice(m_, x_, xx_,  h_,          U, Ux):
        preact = tensor.dot(h_, U)
        preact += x_

        # reset and update gates
        r = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 0, dim))
        u = tensor.nnet.sigmoid(_slice(preact, 1, dim))

        # compute the hidden state proposal
        preactx = tensor.dot(h_, Ux)
        preactx = preactx * r
        preactx = preactx + xx_

        # hidden state proposal
        h = tensor.tanh(preactx)

        # leaky integrate and obtain next hidden state
        h = u * h_ + (1. - u) * h
        h = m_[:, None] * h + (1. - m_)[:, None] * h_

        return h

    # prepare scan arguments
    seqs = [mask, state_below_, state_belowx]
    _step = _step_slice
    shared_vars = [tparams[_p(prefix, 'U')],
                   tparams[_p(prefix, 'Ux')]]

    init_state = tensor.unbroadcast(tensor.alloc(0., n_samples, dim), 0)

    rval, updates = theano.scan(_step,
                                    sequences=seqs,
                                    outputs_info=[init_state],
                                    non_sequences=shared_vars,
                                    name=_p(prefix, '_layers'),
                                    n_steps=nsteps,
                                    strict=True)
    return rval
```

---

As a side note, Keras fixed this issue as [follows](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/theano_backend.py#L433):

```
results, _ = theano.scan(
    _step,
    sequences=inputs,
    outputs_info=[None] + initial_states,
    go_backwards=go_backwards)

# deal with Theano API inconsistency
if type(results) is list:
    outputs = results[0]
    states = results[1:]
else:
    outputs = results
    states = []
```